# How do I make my Python extension take additional arguments?

Tags: python, c++

Consider the following example code that I got off the Python documentation page. It takes one argument right now. I want to make it accept a named argument like "mode=2". So that i can call myext.do_something('/home/crypto/something.jpg', mode=2). The argument passed with mode should be an integer and if it gets something else, I want it to raise an error in Python. How do I go about doing this? I'm thinking I should edit module_functions[] but I don't know what to put in there.

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject * 
do_something(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
   char *filename;
   if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &filename))
      return NULL;

   char *result = do_somethingelse(filename);
   return Py_BuildValue("s", result);
}

static PyMethodDef
module_functions[] = {
    { "do_something", do_something, METH_VARARGS, "do something" },
    { NULL }
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC
initmyext(void)
{
    Py_InitModule("myext", module_functions);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minimal example:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject * 
do_something(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)
{
   char *filename;
   int mode = 2;
   static char *keywords[] = {"filename", "mode", NULL};

   if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "s|i", keywords, &filename, &mode))
      return NULL;

   char *result = do_somethingelse(filename);
   return Py_BuildValue("s", result);
}

static PyMethodDef
module_functions[] = {
    { "do_something", (PyCFunction)do_something, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "do something" },
    { NULL }
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC
initmyext(void)
{
    Py_InitModule("myext", module_functions);
}
```

Comment: g++ -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c python.cc -o python.o
python.cc: In function ‘PyObject* do_something(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
python.cc:8:57: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
    static char *keywords[] = {"filename", "mode", NULL};
                                                         ^
python.cc:8:57: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
python.cc:13:44: error: ‘do_somethingelse’ was not declared in this scope
    char *result = do_somethingelse(filename);

Comment: python.cc: At global scope:
python.cc:21:1: error: invalid conversion from ‘PyObject* (*)(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*) {aka _object* (*)(_object*, _object*, _object*)}’ to ‘PyCFunction {aka _object* (*)(_object*, _object*)}’ [-fpermissive]
 };
 ^
make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: This is valid C code. You need to adapt it for C++.

Comment: The tag says C++, not C.

Comment: In case you didn't notice, I'm not here to do your job. If you're not able to figure it out by yourself (which I did), it's your problem.

Comment: There's no need for hostility. People other than myself will be using this site to find answers. It's not helpful to them if the accepted answer isn't relevant. Upvoted accidently.